# CI Database Error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm freshman in CI.
Today I got an error like this when I learned CI tutorial.
You must use the "set" method to update an entry.

> Filename:
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\ISA2013\ISA2013\system\database\DB_active_rec.php

Line Number: 1174

My Model code like this.

```
class Apply_model extends CI_Model {
    public function add_record($data){
        $query = $this->db->insert('help_user');
        //return;
    }
}
```

And I just coded like that in Control:

```
public function create(){
        $data = array('USER_NUMBER' => $this->input->post('stuNO'),
                      'USER_EMAIL'  => $this->input->post('email'),
                      'USER_INFO'   => $this->input->post('info')
                    );
        $this->apply_model->add_record($data);
        $this->index();
}
```

..when I run class/create, I got the top of error..
Can someone help me?

Comment: In your model, fix this:$this->db->insert('help_user'); to:  $this->db->insert('help_user', $data); -> your method doesn't sending any data to table.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass your data as parameter to $this->db->insert function as mentioned by [nevermind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2045185/nevermind)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by nevermind, you have to pass data array to the insert function. Also please note that data array should be an associative array, where keys will be the table fields and values will be values for the fields.

Answer (score 1):

You don't pass the parameter data into $this->db->insert function. You can change the code line :

```
$query = $this->db->insert('help_user');
```

to:

```
$query = $this->db->insert('help_user', $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

on your model you must like this

```
public function add_record($data)
    {

        $this->db->insert('help_user',$data); //it's more be simple 
    }
```

if you write a return; you will return a null value to your controller
if you write like

```
$query = $this->db->insert('help_user');
```

you just make a variable $query with value $this->db->insert('help_user'); so thats make a error

Answer (score 0):

hey buddy you are missing one parameter and you are not returning the value, you should have

```
return $this->db->insert('help_user', $data);
```